# Cygnus is updating the wrong table

Tags: fiware-cygnus

I have a Cygnus instance running with MySQL sink and I wanted to save every report in the same row, using the same table for every sensor report. So I created the MySql table and configurate Cygnus with:

```
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = $DATABASE
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = $TABLE

cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.attr_persistence = column
cygnusagent.sinks.mysql-sink.table_type = table-by-service-path
```

Evry $ is a replacement of the real name for what it means.

Whenever there is an Orion notification I get this log:

> WARN
>   sinks.OrionSink: Bad context data (Table 
>   '$DATABASE.$TABLE_$ENTITYID_$ENTITYTYPE' doesn't
>   exist)

After reading [this description](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/flume_extensions_catalogue/orion_mysql_sink/index.html#section1.3) I had the idea that Cygnus would try to save the data in a table with the name in `default_service_path`, which is not the case. What do I need to change to make it that way?

Comment: Which version of Cygnus are you using? This is important because the latests version of Cygnus have replaced `the table_type` parameter by `data_model`, being the `table-by-service-path` replaced by `dm-by-service-path` (as stated in the link you mention). In addition, I'm not sure the variable substitution is going to work, and I think the `$DATABASE` value for `default_service` is going to be considered literaly as a string containing a '$' character at the beginning.